# Jquery show or hide elements based on input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I would like to know how to show a div and hide another at the same time.
And that it only does that when I give an **input of 5 or higher**:

```
<div class="InputField InputMeters">
   <input type="tel" name="iFenceMeters" id="FenceMeters" class="AutosubmitCalculator" 
          data-minimum-length="1" tabindex="1" placeholder="00" maxlength="3" value="">
   <div class="FormExclamation Tipped Hidden" id="FormCalculatorExclamationFence">0</div>
</div>
```

this needs to **show:** `<div id="testje" class="CalculatorRight" style="display:none">`

This needs to **hide:** `<div id="SummaryHTML" class="CalculatorRight">`

The code I use now that **only** focuses on input and **not** on input's value:

```
$('#FenceMeters').on('input', function() {
      $('#testje').show();
      $('#SummaryHTML').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like below,

```
   $('#FenceMeters').on('input', function() {
     if($('#FenceMeters').val() != "" && Number($('#FenceMeters').val()) >=5){
              $('#testje').show();
              $('#SummaryHTML').hide();
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the current value and check using [Number.parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt)

```js
$('#FenceMeters').on('input', function() {
  const value = $(this).val();
  if (Number.parseInt(value) >= 5) {
    $('#testje').show();
    $('#SummaryHTML').hide()
  } else {
    $('#testje').hide();
    $('#SummaryHTML').show()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="InputField InputMeters">
  <input type="tel" name="iFenceMeters" id="FenceMeters" class="AutosubmitCalculator" data-minimum-length="1" tabindex="1" placeholder="00" maxlength="3" value="">
  <div class="FormExclamation Tipped Hidden" id="FormCalculatorExclamationFence">0</div>
</div>

<div id="testje" class="CalculatorRight" style="display:none">hidden</div>

<div id="SummaryHTML" class="CalculatorRight">shown</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try below solution.

```js
$('#FenceMeters').on("change paste keyup", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val >= 5) {
    $('#testje').show();
    $('#SummaryHTML').hide();
  } else {
    $('#testje').hide();
    $('#SummaryHTML').show();
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.CalculatorRight {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="InputField InputMeters">
  <input type="tel" name="iFenceMeters" id="FenceMeters" class="AutosubmitCalculator" data-minimum-length="1" tabindex="1" placeholder="00" maxlength="3" value="">
  <div class="FormExclamation Tipped Hidden" id="FormCalculatorExclamationFence">0</div>
</div>
<div id="testje" class="CalculatorRight hidden"> testje </div>
<br/>
<div id="SummaryHTML" class="CalculatorRight">SummaryHTML </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get numeric value of the input by using `parseFloat`, if not a number in the input use 0 as default

```
$('#FenceMeters').on('input', function() {
         var inputValue = parseFloat($(this).val()) || 0;
         if(inputValue>5){
                  $('#testje').show();
                  $('#SummaryHTML').hide();
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

**No Jquery!** Just vanilla javascript. Added `eventListner` on input `keyup` and changed the style for both `div` based on condition. Just for reference.

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("FenceMeters");
let testje = document.getElementById("testje");
let SummaryHTML = document.getElementById("SummaryHTML");
elem.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  if(elem.value > 5){
    testje.style.display = null;
    SummaryHTML.style["display"] = "none"; 
  }
  else{
    testje.style["display"] = "none";
    SummaryHTML.style["display"] = null;
  }  
});
```

```html
<div >
   <input type="number"  id="FenceMeters" maxlength="3"  >
   <div >0</div>
</div>

<div id="testje" style="display:none">
  testje
</div>

<div id="SummaryHTML" >
  SummaryHTML
</div>
```